# How to define element with multiple on() events

Tags: jquery

Let me explain this... If I have something like this

```
$(window).on({
        'hashchange': function(){
            //Do something
        },
        'click' : function(){
            //Do something
        }
    });
```

I know that if I click anything, the click function will be called, but how to select the element I want the `on('click')` to work with.

Like this

```
$(document).on('click','.element_to_call',function(){});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this for event delegation.

```
$(window).on({
    'hashchange': function(){
        //Do something
    },
    'click' : function(){
        //Do something
    }
}, '.element_to_call');
```

Comment: But if I want it only for the click... is that possible or I have to write another on('click') function ?

Comment: I think you'd need to use another `.on()`.

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about from within the function, just reference `e.target`:

```
var $this = $(e.target);
```

In the case that you wanted different handlers based on what was clicked, you could create an object literal that simply held all the handlers. Then from within your window click handler, you prevent the default action, grab the current target, get its id, check to see if that id exists as a function within your handler object literal and if so, call it.

### [See working jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/V6UKM/)

---

### HTML

```html
<section id="elements">
    <h2>Elements</h2>
    <hr />
    <button id="abc">ABC</button>
    <input id="def" type="text" />
    <label id="ghi">GHI</label>
</section>

<section id="results">
    <h2>Results</h2>
    <hr />
    <label/>
</section>
```

---

### JQUERY

```js
var $window = $(window),
    $results = $("#results"),
    $resultsLabel = $results.find("label");

ClickHandler =
{
    abc: function () { showResults( "ABC clicked." ); },
    def: function () { showResults( "DEF clicked." ); }
};

$window.on
({
    "hashchange": function () 
    { 
        // Do something. 
    },
    "click" : function (e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();

        var $this = $(e.target),
            elementName = $this.attr("id");

        if (typeof ClickHandler[elementName] === "function")
            ClickHandler[elementName]();
        else
            clearResults();
    }
});

function clearResults ()
{
    showResults("");
}

function showResults (message)
{
    $results
        .stop(true, true)
        .fadeOut("fast", function () 
        { 
            $resultsLabel.text(message);

            if (message !== "")
                $results.fadeIn("slow"); 
        });
}
```

---

### CSS

```css
html, body
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
    font-family: verdana;
}

hr
{
    margin: 20px 0;
}

#abc 
{
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
}

#def
{
    display: block;
    margin: 20px 0;
}

#ghi
{
    display: block;
    background: green;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
    border: solid 1px blue;
}

#results
{
    display: none;
    margin-top: 40px;
}

#results > label
{
    display: block;
}
```